# Upgrading a project to React 16 with old dependencies

Tags: reactjs

I would like to upgrade a project to React 16, because I have some dependencies that already rely on it. However, I'm also tailing a few very old React packages that I have not found the time yet to upgrade to newer releases that do support React 16. Now I need to buy some time.

My project sources have kept up with the newer releases of React, but I wonder if there's anything that would not be possible to resolve for old dependencies that would cause them to remain completely broken with React 16?

Comment: As long as those packages are not related to React, then I see no problem in using their older versions. If you are using a custom component from a module that uses an older version of React, then you might have problems. Certain things may have gotten deprecated or even obsolete. Make sure your package have been keeping up with the latest versions of React, otherwise you might want to think about how to proceed (find a newer library or try to update the old one yourself, if it is open source).

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file and indicate which deps you're concerned about? And have you tried upgrading and running your test suite? What happens?

Comment: All the dependencies I use have newer releases and they've been ready for React 16 for some time. The problem is that I myself haven't had the time to work through the breaking changes in a timely manner. Thanks for pointing it out, I've updated my question to make it more clearer.

Comment: @AlexMcp I've tried running the newer packages that depend on React 16 with React 15 and it doesn't work (and I really need their latest changes). I haven't tried running the older ones on React 16 yet, but being that I already see deprecating warnings for `React.PropTypes` and `React.createClass` (for example) I know I'm bound to run into some kind of trouble with React 16... I just want to know whether it's something I can work around until if find the time to move these to their newer releases.

Comment: If you don't mind dirty tricks you can do this as a temporary hack: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/913540709013229569

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following this [suggested comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671373/upgrading-a-project-to-react-16-with-old-dependencies#comment80297172_46671373), patching React early on by importing something like the following module before importing olden dependencies should work:

```
import React from 'react'

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import createClass from 'create-react-class'

Object.assign(React, {
  PropTypes,
  createClass
})
```

For projects that were receiving warnings prior to React 16, these then get resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Put this at the top of index.js (or your first file you load):

```
import './patchReact'
import React from 'react'
....
etc
```

// patchReact.js

```
require('react').PropTypes = require('prop-types')
require('react').createClass = require('create-react-class')
```

Credit to Dan Abramov's [tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/913540709013229569).

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, upgrading the project with old dependency into React 16 is gonna break somewhere now or in near future until and unless you don't upgrade other dependencies in your project. But, I can suggest you a way by which you can bypass for quite some time.

```
 {
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Update your dependency of react with this given dependency and remove the node_modules folder and again fire npm install on your package.json to install the new packages for react run and test and build.